# how to log react window.onError errors to file

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to make it possible to log errors, and save/log it to a file on the front end side.

I have a module that handles a window.onError method,

It is called `myModule.onError()` on the React side. From here if their is an error, it shows up in the console.log() like this

[image]

How would i go about logging this error into a file ?

I've tried bundling multiple logging libraries(like winston, buyan, log4js, etc) with my module, and im getting errors from `fs` is not found, to much more errors.

Here is my window on error method, what should i do so it would be possible to log the window.onError errors into a file. How would i bundle it within my module ?

```
function onError(){
    const data = {};
    return window.onerror = ( msg, url,lineNo,columnNo, error) => {
        let string = msg.toLowerCase();
        let substring = 'script error';
        if (string.indexOf(substring) > -1) {
            alert('Script Error: See Browser Console for Detail');
        } 
        else {
            let message = [
                'Message: ' + msg,
                'URL: ' + url,
                'Line: ' + lineNo,
                'Column: ' + columnNo,
                'Error object: ' + JSON.stringify(error)
            ].join(' - ');
            const messageObj = {
                Message: msg,
                URL: url,
                Line: lineNo,
                Column: columnNo,
                ErrorObject: JSON.stringify(error)
            };
            const messObj = JSON.stringify(messageObj)
            console.log(messObj);
            // ourLogger.log('info',messObj);
            // maybe call an axios post passing in the error
            // axios.post('/clinet-log',{messObj} )
            //     .then( res => {
            //         res
            //     })
            console.log(messageObj);
            return messObj;
        }

   };
}

export function onErrorMain(){
    let onErrorinit = onError();
    return onErrorinit;
}
```

Comment: Why do you want a file on the client device? It's possible but it's very unusual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `fs` module in browser, as it's a node library
All you can do is: send http request from browser to server, then save file on server side using `fs`

Pseudo code

```js
/*
BE - BackEnd
FE - FrontEnd

BE: create backend api, something like http://examp.le/sendError
FE: override window.onError
FE: inside window.onError send request to backend
FE: jQuery.post('http://examp.le/sendError', { errorData: 'some error' })
BE: receive the data
BE: write to file and return result
FE: show result on page

*/
```

Comment: can you show how this would be possible, with some pseudo code maybe.